# Get the location of a well known location like Eiffel Tower with google geocoding?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, geocoding, google-geocoder

Im trying to get the Location ( Country,City,Adress ) of well known locations using google Geocoding. I have read the api countless times, i found out how to search with the location of an adress:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Leonidou+21&components=administrative_area%3ALARISA
```

Or A city:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?language=el&components=administrative_area:LARISA|country:GR
```

But cant find how to search for a well known location Like Acropolis,Taj Mahal,Eiffel Tower etc.

Is it even possible with google geocoder ?

Comment: The geocoder is for postal addresses (although it does include some other "places").  The Places API is for places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [places API](https://developers.google.com/places/?csw=1), not locations. ;]